# Prohibit shutdown /s /t 123 forcible closing of hanged programs?

Tags: windows, shutdown

When time come, shutdown will try close apps, waits about 10 seconds, then terminates all apps(Photoshop for example). I need make it to wait forever, or, better, for very long time(~1 day) and after force close all apps.

Comment: Have  you tried `/s /t 86400`? See [Shutdown - Shutdown the computer - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/shutdown.html)

Comment: Yeah you pretty much have it, you just need to calculate your value for /t. /? shows /t xxx     Set the time-out period before shutdown to xxx seconds.
               The valid range is 0-315360000 (10 years), with a default of 30.
               If the timeout period is greater than 0, the /f parameter is
               implied.

Answer (score -1):

I found solution.
When /t greater than 0, this automatically adds /f. Therefore, we must use /t 0 and create task in Task scheduler with command

```
shutdown /s /t 0
```